# Crystal Report: Summarize multiple date fields in one

Tags: date, crystal-reports, report

please help me..I've been trying to search this for weeks but can't find the answer..

Given: Currently I have these dates field on my crystal.

```
   01/01/2015
   02/24/2015
   02/27/2015
   02/28/2015
   02/29/2015
```

How can I summarize it in one field to be like this,

```
   01/01/2015, 02/24/2015, 02/27-2015 - 02-29-2015
```

generally, separate different dates with comma and join dates that are in range or consecutive in order.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this is summarizing or appending multiple rows into single row?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of summarizing the field in crystal report like you mentioned in your question. 
However, you could try a work-around.

Create a Group and group by the 'date' field you want to summarize and then-

1) Create a formula with a shared variable to be placed in the header section of the report:

```
shared stringVar result="";
```

2) Create another formula with the same shared variable to be placed in detail section which concatenates your result into a comma separated array:

```
whileprintingrecords;
shared stringVar result;
if(result='')
    then result:=CStr ({Date1.Date1_Text})
else
    result:=result + "," +CStr ({Date1.Date1_Text});
```

Here ,{Date1.Date1_Text} is the date field which you want to summarize.

3) Create another formula with the same shared variable to be placed at the report footer:

```
shared stringVar result;
NumberVar i;
StringVar array dates  := Split(result,",");

//Here you could put your logic to convert dates to date range.    
//.... 
result; // returns final result
```